# How to validate XML after Maven filtering?

Tags: java, xml, validation, maven, maven-3

Assume that I have a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root property="${my.custom.maven.property}"/>
```

Because `my.custom.maven.property` is obtained by Maven plugin, I can't modify its value and it is non-escaped UTF-8 String, so it may (and it does) contain a special characters like `"`. This would lead to error after packaging or compilation phases (mostly at deployed server...). I want to prevent that situation by XML validation.

The point here is I am using `xml-maven-plugin:validate`. That won't help, because I can't specify that this validation should be done after filtering (well, filtering here means injecting those Maven property value). Plugin config looks really simple:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>validate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <validationSets>
            <validationSet>
                <dir>xml_root</dir>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </validationSet>
        </validationSets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: what do you meant by "Because my.custom.maven.property is obtained by Maven plugin"? Which maven plugin does provide this property and inject it in the build?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html is responsible for those actions, I am using maven-git-commit-id-plugin in this particular case

Comment: Hm..First you mentioned examples...furthermore maven-resources-plugin do not define a property `my.custom.maven.property`.  Apart from that where is the relationship to the examples you referencing to?

Comment: It might be any plugin that just includes some property with value unsafe for XML, what is the point for specifying exact example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven properties injection is handled by the Resources Plugin which has a bind [by default](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) to the `process-resources` phases, while the XML Maven Plugin validate goal has a [default](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validate-mojo.html) binding to the `test` phase, probably too late during your build.

You can move the XML validation earlier in the Maven lifecycle and apply it right after the properties injection binding it to the `process-resources` phase as well as following:

```
<executions>
   <execution>
       <phase>process-resources</phase>
       <goals>
           <goal>validate</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

Note the additional `phase` element.
As such, Maven would inject and then validate the XML and your build will fail (if required) much earlier.

For a full list of phases and their order, check official Maven documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Beware: in case you would use it, some Eclipse (m2e) versions may not like a different phase binding, you can ignore this error as long as the command line build works fine (always trust the command line build).